# Is there any reason not to generate conditional hash codes using GetHashCode in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-statements, gethashcode

In a class I use as a document or document+page identifier, I use the following implementation of GetHashCode. It 'felt' right but since I haven't really seen domain-specific conditioning in this method before, I was wondering if there is a reason not to do so. Of course the ToString method has the same conditioning as well.

```
public override int GetHashCode ()
{
    int hash = 0;

    unchecked
    {
        hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductManufacturer.Value.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductName.Value.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductVersion.Value.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.Guid.Value.GetHashCode();

        if (this.Type != IdentifierType.Document)
        {
            hash = hash * 23 + this.PageNumber.Value.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.PageCount.Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    return (hash);
}
```

**Updated Code based on answers and Eric's links**:

```
public bool Equals (Identifier other)
{
    return (this.Equals(other, this.Type));
}

public override bool Equals (object obj)
{
    return ((obj is HouseOIdentifier) && (this.Equals(obj as Identifier)));
}

public bool Equals (Identifier other, IdentifierType type)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
    {
        result = true;
    }
    else if (!object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
    {
        result
            = (this.Type == other.Type)
            && (this.ProductManufacturer.Key == other.ProductManufacturer.Key)
            && (this.ProductManufacturer.Value == other.ProductManufacturer.Value)
            && (this.ProductName.Key == other.ProductName.Key)
            && (this.ProductName.Value == other.ProductName.Value)
            && (this.ProductVersion.Key == other.ProductVersion.Key)
            && (this.ProductVersion.Value == other.ProductVersion.Value)
            && (this.Guid.Key == other.Guid.Key)
            && (this.Guid.Value == other.Guid.Value)
            ;

        if (type == IdentifierType.Page)
        {
            result
                &= (this.PageNumber.Key == other.PageNumber.Key)
                && (this.PageNumber.Value == other.PageNumber.Value)
                && (this.PageCount.Key == other.PageCount.Key)
                && (this.PageCount.Value == other.PageCount.Value)
                ;
        }
    }

    return (result);
}

public override int GetHashCode ()
{
    int hash = 0;

    unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap.
    {
        hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + this.Type.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductManufacturer.Key.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductManufacturer.Value.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductName.Key.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductName.Value.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductVersion.Key.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.ProductVersion.Value.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.Guid.Key.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + this.Guid.Value.GetHashCode();

        if (this.Type == HouseOfSynergy.FastForm.Core.Identifier.EnumType.Page)
        {
            hash = hash * 23 + this.PageNumber.Key.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.PageNumber.Value.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.PageCount.Key.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.PageCount.Value.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    return (hash);
}

public override string ToString ()
{
    return ("whatever");
}
```

Comment: `ToString` isn't the important counterpart here - `Equals` is. Is your equality check consistent?

Comment: What Jon Skeet said + ensure all the fields/props involved in the calculation are immutable.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Hmmm. No my implementation of `IEquatable<Identifier>` isn't consistent. Thanks. Once I change that, I am assuming there is nothing wrong with using conditioning as long as GetHashCode and Equals are consistent?

Comment: @spender: Yes all fields and properties are immutable. What would I need to change if they were mutable?

Comment: @RaheelKhan: Suppose you hash on a mutable field and then put the object in a hash table and mutate the field. How are you going to get it back out again?  The hash table assumes that it can find the object using the same hash that it was stored with.

Comment: If you are unclear on how to correctly implement a hash code you should stop what you are doing and read my article on the subject before you proceed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you for that link. My takeaway is `"integer returned by GetHashCode must never change while the object is contained in a data structure that depends on the hash code remaining stable"`. This class in internal to the assembly and is not used in any hash sets. I was simply implementing it as a formality since I needed ToString and IEquatable<T>.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: If you genuinely intend that GetHashCode *never* be called on the object then you could always implement it as `{Debug.Fail("Please don't call me!"); return 0;}` but that of course is simply leaving a (polite) bomb around for yourself in the future when suddenly you realize that you could implement some algorithm more efficiently if you just put a few of these in a hash set and then it blows up.

Comment: @EricLippert: I have updated the code in the question area based on guidelines from both your links. Please let me know if you spot any inconsistencies now. It's good to have a reference implementation around. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome! Consider posting your code on codereview.stackexchange.com if you want a review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is fine as long as equal objects have the same hash code. That's the only requirement there is. How you calculate the hash code, that is, whether you use if-statements or not, is not important.

(Also, it would be nice if the hash code never changed during the object's life time, because it breaks pretty much any data structure that uses hash codes. Optimally the object should be immutable.)

Comment: I see what spender meant above about immutable types. So as long as values don't change, mutable types should be fine as well right?

Comment: Sure, all works as long as the hash code stays the same while the object is stored. If you have to modify a field that affects the hash code you have to first remove it and add back again after the modification.

Comment: Thanks. Lastly, in the updated code in my question, there is a conditional exception thrown from Equals if the `Type` value of either operand is `IdentifierType.None`. Should I also duplicate that in GetHashCode or remove it altogether?

Comment: It sounds a little strange that `Equals` should throw an exception in this case; it should tell if the objects are "equal" or not. I would put validation of attribute values somewhere else.

Comment: @RaheelKhan: Joni is correct; neither method should ever throw. You should fix your implementation of `Equals`.  If you are not clear on how to write a correct implementation of `Equals` then see http://ericlippert.com/2013/10/07/math-from-scratch-part-six-comparisons/ . I note that your implementation doesn't handle nulls correctly either.

Comment: @Joni: Makes sense. That validation should be done earlier on before `Equals` can be called.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you for that link. I was looking for something to use a reference point.